# Writing test in facebookincubator/create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am now studying ReactJS at first time.

From the https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-writing-a-counter-reducer-with-tests

boiler plate : `facebookinculator/create-react-app`
Test by using: `npm test`

The main reason why I decided to not use the plain online website to do practicing is because I want to familiar with real tools as much as I can.
Here is my code.

```
export const counter = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1;
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And my `utils.test.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import counter from '../utils/utils';

it('expect 1 to be return from reducer', () => {
  expect(counter(0, {type: 'INCREMENT'})).toEqual(1)
});
```

**Error**:

```
 FAIL  src/utils/utils.test.js
  ● expect 1 to be return from reducer

    TypeError: (0 , _utils2.default) is not a function

      at Object.<anonymous>.it (src/utils/utils.test.js:5:30)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
          at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

 PASS  src/App.test.js

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.062s, estimated 1s
Ran all test suites.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

**Question:**
Where am I wrong?
I have check with docs already.
Also I had tried `expect(1).toEqual(1)` to confirm my configuration is correct.

**References:**
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#toequalvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `counter` is a **named import** as opposed to a **default import**.

Try using this to import `counter`:

```
import { counter } from '../utils/utils';
```

The syntax you are currently using only works if you were to export your `counter` as the default for the `utils` module.

Comment: Please wait 3 minutes. Thank you for your fast response so much.